# How to delete all repeated words from the string even none of the repeated words remain?

Tags: java, arrays, string

### Sample input

```
"Hello hi hi stackoverflow remain only Hello "
```

### output:

```
"stackoverflow remain only"
```

Here is my code I tried

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String name = "Hello hi stackoverflow remain only Hello hi";
    String ar[] = name.split("\\s");
    ArrayList<String> dup = new ArrayList<String>();//duplicate words
    ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        res.add(ar[i]);
        String del = ar[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < ar.length; j++) {
            if (ar[j].equals(dup)) {
                dup.add(del);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < dup.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < res.size(); j++) {
        if (st[i].equals(st2[j])) {
            res.remove(res.IndexOf(j));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and Hi are "the same"? What about "hey" and "yo"?

Comment: He has "Hello" and "hi" twice in his input, I think he means only for words whose characters match exactly.

Comment: What are your constraints? For example, without using streams, I'd probably parse to a `Map<String,Integer>`, and then output everything that had a count == 1. But if you have to use a `List`, then the solution would be different.

Comment: What about to make this two-fold? First count each word. In a second iteration only copy those words which have a count of one? Just an idea, perhaps it helps.

Comment: "hey" and "yo" these are different words. If any words repeated then in output they all should be deleted.

Comment: I think the first thing you should do is try to define what "repeated" means.  Then encapsulate that idea into a method (I assume that making a class isn't part of the assignment).  Right now I'm having trouble reading your code because it's all just one big method that tries to do everything.  Break it up into higher level steps and it should be easier to understand how to code it.

Comment: You can use LinkedHashSet to store these words and then simply iterate over it.

Comment: It's great that you have the sample input, expected output, and the code you tried - it would be even better if you also gave the real output/runtime error you are currently experiencing, as this would help us pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8 you can use [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) and [`Collection.frequency`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency-java.util.Collection-java.lang.Object-) like this :

```
String text = "Hello hi hi stackoverflow remain only Hello ";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(text.split("\\s+")));
list.removeIf(element -> Collections.frequency(list, element) > 1);
```

**The idea is to remove all element which has a frequency great than 1.**

Outputs

```
[stackoverflow, remain, only]
```

---

to get back a String you can just use :

```
text = String.join(" ", list);// "stackoverflow remain only"
```

Comment: What's the time complexity of this? `O(n^2)`?

Comment: I think so @BoristheSpider I try to make it more performance!

Comment: Hi @YCF_L thanks for your help, but still I couldn't get some error getting saying "Test.java:25: error: illegal start of expression
                list.removeIf(element -> Collections.frequency(li
1);"

Comment: List<String> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(name.split("\\s+")));
ListIterator ltr = dup.listIterator();
while(ltr.hasNext()){
String element= (String)ltr.next();
list.removeIf(element -> Collections.frequency(list, element) > 1);
}
System.out.println(list); 
}

Comment: @BoristheSpider a slight improvement could be `list.removeIf(element -> list.stream().filter(e -> e.equals(element)).limit(2).count() > 1);`?

Comment: @Tavash I don't understand your code, why you are using `ListIterator` ?

Comment: First i find duplicate values and put it to a list, then using iterator I just pull up one word and pass it to your prescribed code.

Comment: @Tavash if you frind the duplicate words you don't need my code, you can just use `list.removeAll(dup);` [check this demo](https://ideone.com/TIx7UN)

Comment: @Aominè not any better really - and the streaming of a collection you are removing from looks dodgy to me. Your two pass approach is the best so far - but still rather ugly.

Comment: step:1 split string into array using space delimeter
step:2 creates two ArrayList one for whole string and other one for duplicates words
step:3 while finding duplicates i simply picked one words from splited array and compare it to rest of all words if any match occured put it into duplicate ArrayList.
step:4 finally I got a list of duplicate words and called whole_words_list.removeAll(duplicate_list); as @YCF_L suggested. great feeling, Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks too complicated. instead, using the Java-8 stream library, you can do:

```
List<String> result = 
         Pattern.compile("\\s")
                .splitAsStream(name)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e,
                        LinkedHashMap::new,
                        Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or if you want the receiver type as a String then you can use the `joining` collector.

```
String result = 
         Pattern.compile("\\s")
                .splitAsStream(name)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e,
                        LinkedHashMap::new,
                        Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Comment: Thanks @Aomine  and of course my code is too complicated, but I just try solve question which I faced in interview.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
Stream.of(str.split(" "))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.summingInt(n -> 1)))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e->e.getValue() == 1)
            .map(e->e.getKey())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
```

---

or like this

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
List<String> orginal = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(as));
orginal.removeAll(Arrays.stream(as)
                  .filter(str -> !set.add(str))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: does work sequentially, but running it in parallel will cause non-deterministic results due to `.filter(str -> !set.add(str))`. However, since this question is not concerned about parallelism +1 :).

Comment: FYI I run your second code snippet using a parallel stream and got `[hi, hi, stackoverflow, remain, only]`

Comment: `String text = "Hello hi hi stackoverflow remain only Hello ";
      
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        String as[] = text.split("\\s");
        List<String> orginal = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(as));
        orginal.removeAll(Arrays.stream(as).parallel()
                .filter(str -> !set.add(str))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        System.out.println(orginal);` make sure to run the code several times or many times and you'll notice the results differ in some runs.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different variant to @YCF_L's answer, short-circuiting where possible.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(text.split("\\s")));
list.removeIf(element -> list.stream()
                             .filter(e -> e.equals(element)) 
                             .limit(2) // short circuit
                             .count() > 1);
```

**Update:**

The above code works, but if you're concerned with streaming over a list you're removing from then a safer alternative would be:

```
List<String> result = 
      list.stream()
          .filter(element -> list.stream().filter(e -> e.equals(element)).limit(2)
                                 .count() == 1) 
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Not keen on a `stream()` over the same `Collection` you are currently calling `removeIf` from - there's no reason why it shouldn't work, but it feels wrong. Also, this is still `O(n^2)` with a linear search over the data.

Comment: @BoristheSpider then i guess a safer approach would be `List<String> result = list.stream()
                .filter(element -> list.stream().filter(e -> e.equals(element)).limit(2).count() == 1)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());` and yes agreed on the time complexity.

Comment: @BoristheSpider as for streaming over the same list I am removing from, I can't really think of a situation where it would cause a problem as by the time an element is removed we've already finished the streaming or I'm I missing something?

Comment: I don't see why an implementation of `removeIf` might not store up "stuff to be removed" and the remove it in one go at the end - this could cause unexpected behaviour if you assume that the remove of the element happens immediately. Don't think that causes a problem in this case, but I still don't like the look of it...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks for clarifying, but yeah I've also provided a _safer_ alternative in my previous comment which I am confident will guarantee the same behaviour.

Comment: @ali agreed that it's not the best readability but if you compare this and the code snippet in the question, surely it's _way_ better right? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
    String statement = "Hello hi stackoverflow remain only Hello hi";
    String res = "";
    for (String word : Arrays.asList(statement.split(" "))) {
        String remain = statement.replaceFirst(word, "");
        if(remain.contains(word)) {
            remain=statement.replaceAll(word, "");
        }else {
            res+=word+" ";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: Hi @Mohammad ,output should't contain any repeated values like if "Hello" appears more than once then in output it wouldn't came even single time.